# Searching multiple files for multiple words

Tags: notepad++

I have to search trough a huge amount of `.txt` files. I know I can do multiple words search, but here's my problem. I want my results to only be the `.txt` files that contain all of the words of the search entry.

For example:

**File 1**:

```
test1
```

**File 2**:

```
 test1
 test2
```

Search files for `test1` and `test2` will only result in showing File 2.

Hope someone can help me out.
Thanks

Comment: How many words are in your search entry? You could use grep: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5915770/1423890

Comment: Do you want to identify files that contain all the words, or do you want to find lines that contain all the words? It is a simple task in Perl, something like `perl -ne "print if m/one/ && m/two/ && m/three/" *.txt`.

Answer (score 58):

If you are using Notepad++ editor (like the tag of the question suggests), you can use the great "Find in Files" functionality.

Go to `Search > Find in Files` (*Ctrl+Shift+F* for the keyboard addicted) and enter:

- Find What = `(test1|test2)`
- Filters = `*.txt`
- Directory = enter the path of the directory you want to search in. You can check `Follow current doc.` to have the path of the current file to be filled.
- Search mode = `Regular Expression`

Comment: Is there a way to use a list of strings in an input file as "Find What" and search in list of files under a folder. The output would be list of files against each string in an input file.

Comment: Not with Notepad++. A few lines of script (Python or Perl) would do the job though. Tell me if you need help writing it

Comment: Surely this would find File 1 as well when it shouldn't?

Comment: @Lilienthal what do you mean?

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT. The OP is asking for a way to search for files containing both test1 and test2 somewhere in them. File 1 only contains test1 and shouldn't be a hit, but with `|` it is. I suppose `((test1.*test2)|(test2.*test1))` might work but that doesn't really scale well.

Comment: flawless answer!!

Comment: @Lilienthal  I guess I got confused by the sentence "*Search files for test1 and test2 will only result in showing File 2.* " ... using "**shall**" there would have avoided any confusion. Indeed, the regex you suggest is what he needs but does not scale well... For complex stuff, few lines of Perl or Python would do the trick better. On the other hand, the OP did not manifest much so I will leave my solution like that :)

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT. No problem, mainly pointed it out because I've been looking for the same thing as the OP and have run into a dead end with Notepad++. A solution to this would involve a more advanced search tool probably.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Notepad++ editor
Goto ctrl + F choose tab 3 find in files and enter:

1. Find What = text1*.*text2
2. Filters : *.*
3. Search mode = Regular Expression
4. Directory = enter the path of the directory you want to search in. You can check Follow current doc. to have the path of the current file to be filled.

Comment: This won't work if `text1` comes after `text2`, that's why the original question has a better Regex.

Comment: Also, I fixed your formatting, please take note next time you post of how the formatting works on Stack Overflow.

Comment: yes but you can change Find What = text2*.*text1. I Think its true better text1|text2

Comment: yes i see. it the first time i answer question on stackoverflow

Comment: If you change it, it won't work for the other way round. The other answer is the only one that makes sense.

Comment: The `1*.*` part of your answer should be, I believe, `1.*`. The `1*.*` means zero or more `1`s then zero or more other characters and a simple `.*` has the same effect. But that would also match against `test3xxxtest2` which is not wanted.

Answer (score -2):

It is another "if you use X" solution, but if you use GitHub, you can use search bar to find code in your repository. It will then list your files matching that code part.

Comment: Can you please explain how to do the search as wanted by the question. Just saying *"use GitHub"* does not answer the question.

Comment: I thought it's really straightforwardly shown in GitHub itself, this is why I didn't explain it clearer. 
If you open your own GitHub repository (or someone elses), then you will see search bar on left top side (or middle-right top side, if not logged in). Here you write code part you want to search, and from menu appearing after that you choose "in this repository". It redirects you to site with listed elements of your repository, first being code (and files where searched code appear). Only limit I found: you can't search for longer code fragments, so it limits you to single line.

Comment: The original question is not a general how to do a search, it is about how to search for a specific set of textual items. That is why the question is interesting. Your answer completely avoids the point of the original question.