# Mixed Content: The page at 'url' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image in Opencart

Tags: php, ssl, ssl-certificate, opencart, opencart2.x

I have one issue in my [Opencart page](https://www.flo-promotion.com/). I recently noticed that green bar into browser is not active, and checked my console for errors. I see this warnings:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'siteurl' was loaded over
> HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://siteurl/image/catalog/category/1.png'. This content should also be
> served over HTTPS.

I checked admin/config.php and have set this:

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'https://siteurl.com/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'https://siteurl.com/');

 // HTTPS
 define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://siteurl.com/admin/');
 define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'https://siteurl.com/');

 // DIR
 define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/public_html/admin/');
 define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/public_html/system/');
 define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/public_html/image/');
 define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/home/public_html/admin/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/home/public_html/admin/view/template/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/home/public_html/system/config/');
 define('DIR_CACHE', '/home/public_html/system/storage/cache/');
 define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', 
'/home//public_html/system/storage/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/home/public_html/system/storage/logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', 
'/home//public_html/system/storage/modification/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', '/home/public_html/system/storage/upload/');
define('DIR_CATALOG', '/home/public_html/catalog/');
```

The same configuration I have is also in siteurl.com/config.php file, but Chrome still give me that yellow warnings, and for that dont mark my site as secured. How do I resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: Search your code base and see where you call `1.png`.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** AS the error says:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'siteurl' was loaded over  HTTPS, but
>   requested an insecure image
>   'http://siteurl/image/catalog/category/1.png'. This content should
>   also be  served over HTTPS.

You are serving insecure image.

Try to find this line in your code/application:

```
http://siteurl/image/catalog/category/1.png
```

and replace it with httpS prefix.

so finally everything to be secured in your platform must be served from `HTTPS` and not `HTTP`

Open your browser debugger , go to network or console and debug accordingly.

**UPDATE:** also make sure in your cart setting:

Please go to admin area=> System=>Setting=>Edit Store=>Server=> Enable Use SSL in Security part

**Update:**  October 17

You can also try the following:

- **Important!** [Create a full backup for your web application](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/cpanel/cpanel-file-manager/complete-cpanel-backup) (files & databases ...etc) < cPanel example.
- Enable debug mood in your app if that is available. Through configuration file, [PHP Error Log](https://stackoverflow.com/a/845025/7735285) and view server's error log even check your browsers' Dev Tool (F12 in Chrome browser) ... this is a good start to track down an issue in general and HTTPS Mixed content in your case.
- Disable any custom theme and use default one.
- Disable plugins one by one and test after each.
- Update core files to the latest version ([bugs happen](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/issues/4102)).
- Update theme to the latest // some changes and customization might be lost. (ex. For WordPress you can use child-theme to safely update parent theme from source)
- Update plugins one by one (Backup any customization)
- After each step test.
- Check your web application's Forum for similar issues and solutions.
- Contact your web application developer after trying your best.

Advanced Tip: Take on insecure image and track back to origin where it starts loaded through HTTP and not HTTPS

Some tools that might help you debug and track down the issue:

- [Download free Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org). [Learn how to find a string from bulk files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17874867/7735285).
- Browsers' console and Dev. ([F12 in Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/))
- Learn Dev. tools as deep as possible if you are dealing with bugs as a routine and not just a detour case.  F12 sometimes could save you days of debugging; spend some hours learning what is behind these function keys.

Comment: if this is the answer to your question you may wish to mark it as answer so others get use of it as well , in addition to let users know this is what you need.

Comment: Im trying to find where that images are hardcoded but dont can find it into template.

Comment: you could post your site URL here or try to use notepad++ search for files. Do you know it?

Comment: first create a backup then try what is in [This post](https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=103177). Also if that is not the issue, try to bulk search and replace in your template for http into https...find notepad++ search in files feature , check this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkX6R.png)

Comment: Please go to admin area=> System=>Setting=>Edit Store=>Server=> Enable Use SSL in Security part.